# Cannot invoke <method> with and argument list of type '(String)'

Tags: xcode, swift, viewcontroller, appdelegate

Im trying to write an OSX app. A functionality of this app is that it displays the machine IP address.
The address is fetched when the program is opened (AppDelegate.swift):

```
@NSApplicationMain class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

      var ipadd:String = ""
      var path:String = ""
      var status:String = ""


      func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
             ipadd = getIFAddress()  //<-- ip stored in here as String
             println(ipadd)   //successfully prints out the ip
             ViewController.setIpDisp(ipadd)   //error on this line

      }
   ...
 }
```

And in ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ip: NSTextField!
    ...

    func setIpDisp(ipin: String){
         ip.stringValue = ipin 
    }
```

To be exact, the error is "Cannot invoke 'setIpDisp' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Thanks

Comment: The function isn't static. You need an instance to call it on. I think the right idea is to send out a message and process that message in your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AppDelegate` is trying to call a `ViewController` method that is updating an `@IBOutlet` in the view controller's view. It needs a valid `ViewController` instance to do that.

But this is backwards: The app delegate should not be trying to call view controller methods. The view controller can call methods/properties of the app delegate, but the app delegate really shouldn't be calling view controller methods.

If you need to update the IP number field in the view controller, then the view controller should be initiating this (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`):

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ip: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        updateIpDisp()
    }

    func updateIpDisp() {
        let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        ip.stringValue = appDelegate.getIFAddress()
    }

}
```

Or, if you wanted, the `AppDelegate` set some `ipadd` string property in its `init` method (not `applicationDidFinishLaunching`), and then the `updateIpDisp()` method could retrieve the property's value from the app delegate, too. (Given that IP numbers are dynamic and can change, that doesn't seem right to me, but do it however you want.) Anyway, that might look like:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var ipadd: String!

    override init() {
        super.init()

        ipadd = getIFAddress()
    }

}
```

and

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ip: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        updateIpDisp()
    }

    func updateIpDisp() {
        let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        ip.stringValue = appDelegate.ipadd
    }

}
```

But the view controller should be requesting the IP number from the app delegate and updating its own view. But the app delegate has no business calling methods in the view controller(s).

Comment: This one actually worked better. I was having some issues with wrapping when using the first method. I read somewhere that program variables should be stored on AppDelegate from there. So i would set it there, and access it there too. I will use this way instead. Thanks @Rob

Answer (score 1):

Your function isn't static, so make sure to initialise an instance of it, like so

```
    @NSApplicationMain class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
      let viewController = ViewController()

      var ipadd:String = ""
      var path:String = ""
      var status:String = ""


      func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
             ipadd = getIFAddress()  //<-- ip stored in here as String
             println(ipadd)   //successfully prints out the ip
             viewController.setIpDisp(ipadd)   //error on this line

      }
   ...
 }
```

Comment: That eliminates the compile-time error, but is probably not the right solution. He shouldn't be instantiating a dummy `ViewController` instance just so he can call some function. Besides, this will probably result in a runtime error as the implicit unwrapping of the `@IBOutlet` for `ip` in the `ViewController` will likely fail.

Comment: What do you suggest @Rob ?

Comment: @Rob, I am new to development in xcode. In this case, Im obtaining my computer's IP, an action which needs be exactly once at startup. `applicationDidFinishLaunching` provides this for me. I get the IP at launch, and tell a view controller to display this. Unless view controllers have their own "run at startup" methods, i dont know what else i would do. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: @Rob Could you please explain why the implicit unwrapping of the `@IBOutlet` in this case will likely fail during runtime? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig - Because outlets are hooked up when you instantiate the scene from the storyboard. But the manual instantiation of `ViewController()` isn't using the storyboard. It's just creating a `ViewController` instance, and it's not associated with any particular storyboard scene. Thus the outlets would be `nil`. Thus, any attempts to use an outlet with an implicit unwrapping (i.e. a `!`) would fail. You'd get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" runtime error.

Comment: @Rob Thank you. I have forgotten that.